# How to use single quotes in the MySQL query in Python

Tags: python, mysql, quote

So I am trying to create a script with a MySQL Query "show databases like 'login';"

I am able to use string substitution and use "login" but i am unable to get the single quotes around it.

Below is how I am trying to do it but i cant get the single quotes even if I escape it using "\".

```
  db = "'"+val+"'"
  print "DB...", db
  run.cmd("echo 'res = cur.execute(\"SHOW DATABASES like  %s;\")\n' >> /run.py" % (db))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your string is wrapped in double quotes you shouldn't need to escape the single quotes. Just add the `val` directly into the format, then add the single quotes to the string being formatted.

```
run.cmd("echo 'res = cur.execute(\"SHOW DATABASES like  '%s';\")\n' >> /run.py" % (val))
```

Also, is there any reason why you're appending a bash command into a python script?

Comment: This does not work. THe single quotes wont show up in run.py. Not sure why. Have u tried it?

Comment: @user2921139 what function are you pointing at with `run.cmd`? Is it built on top of `subprocess`? It could be an issue with that. A simple `print` replacing the `run.cmd` shows the quotes just fine.

Comment: @user2921139 I'm aware, but what is the `run.cmd` function calling/doing? I'd guess it's something wrong with the code there. Could you provide it?

Comment: Oh no, its just something internal to Python and my programming that I am doing. My way to making it run on a linux system.

Answer (score 0):

SHOW DATABASES like '\'%s\'';\" -> this is what worked.